# How do I pair to a Bluetooth device reliably on Android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

The Bluetooth device I'm working with is known to work reliably with an iOS app. I'm working on the Android version.

The failure I'm seeing looks like this:

- Initially I can discover and connect to the device and use it correctly. Pairing happens automatically when I try to connect.
- I then reset the device itself by holding down its reset button.

After this, I can no longer use the device. The symtoms I'm seeing are as follows:

1. The bondState is returned as BOND_NONE. If I call createBond(), it returns true, but no bonding is initiated.
2. If I ignore the bond state I can still discover the device's services and characteristics. However the first time I try to write to a characteristic, it fails (I never get the expected 'onCharacteristicWrite' callback).

I realize that I may have in part brought this on myself by resetting my device, but in practice my users are going to do this, so I'd like to have my app be able to recover from it.

Do I need to somehow "undo" the previous bonding or tell Android to "forget" the device?

Thanks,
Frank